# Retrieving data from user input and save it to mongoose model

Tags: javascript, ejs, mongoose-schema, nested-object

This is my model shema:

```
const DemoSchema = new Schema({
    rowOne: {
        colOne: {
            one: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
            two: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
            three: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
        },
    },
    rowTwo: {
        colOne: {
            one: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
            two: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
            three: {
                name: String,
                qty: Number,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

When I do this it saves data to my model:

```
const product = await new Regal({
    rowOne: { colOne: { two: { name: productName, qty: productQty } } },
});
product.save();
```

My question is, how can I replace rowOne, colOne and two with user input?

I tried this:

```
const row  = req.body.rows // this must be rowOne or rowTwo
const column = req.body.column // colOne or other (colOne to colNine)
const col = req.body.col // one, two or three
const productName = req.body.name
const productQty = req.body.qty
```

Attempt 1:

```
const product = await new Regal({ `${row}`: { `${column}`: { `${col}`: { name: productName, qty: productQty }}}});
```

'Error --> Property Assignment expected.'

Atempt 2:

```
const product = await new Regal(`{${row}: { ${column}: { ${col}: { name: ${productName}, qty: ${productQty} } } } }`);
```

'Error --> Parameter "obj" to Document() must be an object, got {rowOne: { colOne: { one: { name: Milk, količina: 250 } } } }'

Comment: '{ name: Milk, količina: 250 } } } }' real --> { productName: Milk, productQty: 250 } } } }'

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables as keys of objects using square brackets.

```
let user = 'username';
let newObj = { [user]:'saloni' }
```

this will create an object like `{username:saloni}`.
This way you can replace rowOne, colOne, and two with user input by storing them in a variable and then use it.